# A class that does not coincide with the class of all sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This must be trivial, so my apologies to specialists in logic. I am trying to study the Morse-Kelley theory, and this is a continuation of my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681239/introductory-textbooks-on-morse-kelley-set-theory).

Suppose $X$ is a class, that does not coincide with the class $V$ of all sets:
$$
X\ne V.
$$
Is it possible that this automatically means that there exists a subset $Y\subseteq X$ which is not an element of $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  By the axiom of foundation applied to $V\setminus X$, if $X$ is not all of $V$, then there is some $Y\in V\setminus X$ such that no element of $Y$ is in $V\setminus X$.  This is exactly a set $Y$ such that $Y\subseteq X$ but $Y\not\in X$.

(Incidentally, if you want to do the same argument in ZF, you have to do something more complicated like take a $Y\not\in X$ and then apply foundation to the transitive closure of $Y$, since you can't apply foundation to classes directly.  Or you could use [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick), but I'm guessing that would be circular in this context since this statement is likely being used to prove that $V=\bigcup V_\alpha$.)

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you, Eric!

Comment: And the assumption that $X$ is transitive is extra. So I'll edit the question with your permission.

Comment: As to ZF: actually, it's a puzzle for me, why people like ZF so much. MK seems to be much stronger (and more simple), what do people find in ZF?