# Are there any online sources/books that could help me further study set theory?

Tags: set-theory, self-learning, online-resources

I would like to study set theory more intuitively. Searching the internet for this will only provide study for the basics of set theory (unions, intersections, etc.). There are topics I would like to know about, like posets and lattices that require further understanding of set theory. Even if there are books I could buy on Amazon that you could recommend, that would be great. However, I would prefer to study directly from a computer.

Comment: See  [This good question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251490/textbooks-on-set-theory/251888#251888)

Comment: I found a large number of items with this google search: [notes + "set theory" + .pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=notes+%22set+theory%22+.pdf)

Comment: Excuse my self-promotion, but I wrote something that you might find useful. http://karagila.org/2016/the-five-whs-of-set-theory/