# What are good books cover these topics?

Tags: book-recommendation

Sets: sets and their elements, finite and infinite sets, operations on sets (unions, intersections and complements), relations between sets(inclusion, equivalence), non equivalent infinite sets, cardinal numbers.

Comment: Just searching "books on set theory" gives loads of results, what was wrong with those questions? [An example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251490/textbooks-on-set-theory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classical book on these subjects is Paul Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*.