# Set Theory Foundations book recommendation (meta-math)

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, book-recommendation, foundations

I'm looking for a book on set theory foundations that goes into the metamathematics of it all.  I worked through Kleene's *Introduction to Metamathematics*.  In that text he proves godels incompleteness as well as gives proofs of some reductions of classical number theory into intuitionistic number theory.  I'm now left with wanting to know the next step in studying math foundations.  Kleene explored some details of the how one would build a theory in first-order logic (the eliminability of definitions, etc.).  I did very much enjoy that, and would love a book then constructs a theory in first-order (not necessary entirely in first-order but reducible to such).

I poked through a sample of *The Foundations of Set Theory*, Fraenkel, and was really intrigued by the table of contents.  However, after looking a little deeper, I found that there weren't
many proofs presented in the text.  Mainly references just references to other publications and such.

So I would love some recommendations on foundations that include topics like the independence of the axiom of choice, what theorems of ZFC can we reduce to ZF.  Maybe even some intuitionistic set theory (I saw that was mentioned in Fraenkel) or alternate foundations.  And it would be awesome if it went in to some philosophical perspectives on foundations of math.  Although, this may all be too much to ask for in one book I understand.

Comment: I really like Kunen's "Set Theory: An Introduction to Indepence Proofs", Jech's "Set Theory" and Suppes' "Axiomatic Set Theory".

Comment: Also, about my recommendations, go for the earliest prints

Comment: @NuntractatusesAmável  ok will do .  I just looked at Kunen, I like the topics in there a lot.   what is more preferable about the earlier prints?

Comment: I think that they are more directed towards independence proofs in the earlier books, whereas the newer ones opt for a more general view of set theory, and it gets a little too clumped. Also, they opted for a more intuitive approach in the more recent editions, leaving behind some details concerning to the fact that set theory is a first order theory.

Comment: my comment actually applies only for Kunen and Jech

Comment: See [Textbooks on set theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/251490/13130).

Comment: See [Kunen's Foundations](https://books.google.it/books?id=_B_oQQAACAAJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enjoyed Robert Vaught's book when I took his course at Berkeley in the late $80$'s, if you can find a copy.