# Ideal textbook to study the indepence of CH

Tags: logic, set-theory, book-recommendation, forcing

I know that the question about logic, axiomatic set theory and continuum hypothesis (CH) textbooks was asked many times here. Say, the following link contains a huge list of introductory set-theoretic books:

[Textbooks on set theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251490/textbooks-on-set-theory)

My question is somehow concrete and comes after a month of attempts to study the independence of CH. Mainly, I've tried to learn Kunen's and also Jech's "Set theory". The first chapters in both books contained basic information on the ordinals and cardinals. Though the material is familiar to me (from Kuratowski's "Set theory"), it seemed that almost all the proofs are not complete. Thus, I didn't risk to go on reading these books. I've also tried to take a glance at another books (including all the books from the link above) and wasn't satisfied again. My ideal book is the following:

1. Contains *all the proofs* leading to the independence of CH and helping to understand the forcing technique
2. The material has to be introduced in a *clear* way without philosophy (alas, that's why Cohen's original book doesn't fit)
3. Reflects the *classic approach* based on introducing ZFC (that's why Halbeisen's "Combinatorial set theory" doesn't fit)
4. Is *concentrated on the topic* (say, it may not contain proofs from model theory, or extra-advanced set theory; also, I'm not interested in applications to analysis, that's why Ciesielski's book isn't the best variant)
5. Reflects necessary (for the further material) results (and their proofs) on the *ordinals and cardinals*

I understand that I have to make some compromise, or to work not with just one book. That's why I'd like to ask the opinion of those who had the similar problem and, finally, managed to understand the independence proof. What book or books were finally useful for you? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if you read French, but [Théorie des ensembles from Patrick Dehornoy](https://www.amazon.com/Th%C3%A9orie-ensembles-Introduction-th%C3%A9orie-linfini/dp/2916352406) would almost cover your requirements. Its intent is to prove independence of AC and CH with detailed proves from the beginning of set theory.

Comment: So Jech is not good enough?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thanks a lot, I didn't hear about it before. Alas, I'm not good with French. Will try to find the translated version.

Comment: @JCAA Actually, two of Jech's books I've tried to read are well-organizied. Probably, I'll continue to work with them but now they're a bit advanced for me since not all the proofs are clear.

Comment: @ElmarGuseinov Unfortunately, I don't think that an English translation exists yet.

Comment: I'm confused, what's not classical in Halbeisen? Also, "proofs seem incomplete" is a **bad** excuse for not reading a book. You're here to learn, not to read a novel. Learning happens by filling in the gaps yourself. Also, Halbeisen's book is an excellent introduction to forcing.

Comment: I don't think Jech is the "best book". To be frank, I don't like his approach to forcing, and if you only read up to the point of forcing the negation of CH, you will miss out *a lot* of good and important information about forcing. But the overall question is what do you want to do with this? Is this just a goalpost in the study of set theory, or are you just looking to check a box on your bucket list before you move to studying algebra or whatnot? Different goals will have different book recommendations.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I actually have the giant plans. First, I think that techniques like forcing and theorems like Godel's first incompleteness theorem are practically basic in math. It's seems to me a bit strange when someone tries to prove something even not thinking about whether the conjecture is provable at all. I'd like to create a maximally clear system (or a variant of such a system) that generates consistent sentences and check whether this list intersects with some known list of open problems (say, in group, or number theory). I'm not going to be a set-theorist but think it's the future.

Comment: Which Kunen book are you referring to?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Set theory: an introduction to independence proofs

Comment: Cohen's original book is philosophical???