# learning set theory from Jech

Tags: set-theory

A friend and I would like to learn axiomatic set theory. He and I are both comfortable writing proofs in first order logic. A teacher recommended that we use Axiomatic Set Theory by Suppes, but it seems a bit dated. Jech's Set Theory seems to be a very thorough book, and is more modern than Suppes. Would learning set theory from Jech be too ambitious? I went through the first chapter a while ago and enjoyed it, though it was pretty dense.

Comment: Jech and Kunen are the classics. One way or another you will have to study them. I recommend the 1st ed of Jech over the third. You can read the third when you know more.

Comment: which kunen book?

Comment: Yeah, definitely don't use Suppes. Lots of better options https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251490/textbooks-on-set-theory

Comment: @TsviBenschar I learned from the 1980 Kunen book... It's hard to say for sure but I expect I would have had a harder time with the newer version. (Also it's hard to say for sure what will work for you since it has almost as much to do with style as substance. I'd say just try to read from a few different places and see where it takes you.)

Comment: @TsviBenschar Also, if you do Kunen 80, I'd recommend skipping chapter 2 at first. 1,3,4,5,6 flow very nicely without it.

Comment: Really, set theory quickly becomes hard. Start with reader friendly books, such as Cunningham or Halmos, or even Lipschutz.

Comment: Suppes' introduction to logic contains a good introductory chapter on set theory.