# Which Concepts to master before studying about large cardinals?

Tags: self-learning, advice, large-cardinals

I am a undergraduate student interested in large cardinals since I've watched a youtube video called "How to count past infinity", and the concept of inaccessible cardinal that is introduced in the video have made me feel extremely curious about other "larger" Cardinals.

Since then, I have tried to research about large cardinals by myself (My university's only set theory class did not teach me about them), I have looked up the book "The higher infinite", some other papers that could be found on the internet, and even wikipedia pages. However, I have been making very little progress, and I feel like I'm not understanding the concepts because of my low mathematical maturity.

For example, Some books introduced the "filter", and I don't quite understand for what use did someone define a "filter", and of course the usage of it.

So my questions are:

(1) Am I going through the struggles that everyone else have also experienced it?

(2) My university's set theory class only taught me up to definitions and some theorems about functions and relations, am I missing some other "basics" about set theory to learn large cardinals?

(3) If I have did missed some knowledge about set theory, where should I start now, and how should I improve my mathematical maturity?

Thank you.

Comment: Based on your description of your university's set theory class, it seems it was mostly about _naive_ set theory, not about _axiomatic_ set theory. If that's true, then that's where your problem lies -- you need to learn the basics of axiomatic set theory first. You can get better answers to this question by being more explicit about what your set theory class covered: did you learn about the axioms of ZFC? Did you learn about well-orders, ordinals and cardinals? What (sort of) theorems did you prove at the end of the course?

Comment: @MeesdeVries The course did not cover ZFC nor well-orders, ordinals and cardinals, I've learnt about ordered pairs (and theorems like If (a,b) = (c,d), then a=c and b =d), Basics about functions like Injective, bijective, and that's pretty much it.

Comment: @MeesdeVries The hardest exercise that I have done would probably be proving: Let A be a set and 2 be a class consisting of two elements 0 and 1. Then 2^A and P(A) are in one-to-one correspondence

Comment: If you are still interested in set theory and you are native in Korean (sorry if it is not the case: I guessed it from your name), please get in touch in my email. You may find my email address from my website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mees de Vries' answer is actually a *lower* bound on the prerequisites for studying large cardinals. Not only is a solid background in axiomatic (specifically, $\mathsf{ZFC}$-based) set theory necessary, you will also need a solid understanding of the basics of model theory in order to appreciate what the various large cardinal axioms are really doing. For example, a basic early exercise is that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (if consistent) cannot prove the existence of inaccessible cardinals. There are two ways to prove this:

- Showing that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is an inaccessible cardinal" proves $Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ and then invoking the second incompleteness theorem.
- Observing that, $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provably, the cumulative hierarchy up to the least inaccessible (assuming such exists) is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There are no inaccessible cardinals."

Each of these requires a decent understanding of what models and proofs are and how they interact. And things only get more complicated from here; the "large" large cardinals (such as *measurable cardinals*) really only make sense against the backdrop of model theory and in particular the notion of **elementary embeddings**. The fastest responsible route to large cardinals in my opinion basically consists of a pair of semester-long classes (ideally taken separately so as to not overload the student), one in general logic/model theory including compactness and Lowenheim-Skolem theorems and the other in axiomatic set theory.

Comment: Thank you for the addition!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and I apologize for such a late response. I could not use my phones for about 6 weeks because I'm going through the military servicd in Korea. Your answer is the most detailed answer I've heard, and I will make sure to follow your advice. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

A prerequisite for learning about large cardinals is having a basic understanding of *axiomatic* set theory. Typically this means knowing about the axioms of ZFC, about well-orders and ordinals, about cardinalities, and about transfinite induction.

Based on the comments it seems that your university's set theory course covered *naive* set theory: presumably this included an informal notion of what a set is, the definition of a relation and a function, notions like surjectivity, injectivity, bijectivity, and the power set. These are good basic skills to have (for any mathematician!) but does not really get you started on the mathematical field of set theory.

You can compare the difference between naive and axiomatic set theory to the difference between high school, where you use real numbers all the time without really knowing what they are, and your first real analysis course, where you (probably) "define" the real numbers to be an ordered field where every bounded above (below) set of numbers has a least upper (greatest lower) bound.

Thus, if you want to learn about large cardinals, you will have to learn some axiomatic set theory first, or at least in parallel. I do not have a particular recommendation, but the answers to [Textbooks on set theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251490/textbooks-on-set-theory) seem to have some opinions on the matter. :-)

Edit: definitely do not forgo reading Noah Schweber's answer, even if (like at the time of this edit) it has fewer upvotes. He's much more of an expert than me!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and I apologize for late response. I could not use my phone for weeks since April 10th because of military service (Most Korean man have to go to the army for at least one and a half year), I really really appreciate your answer, and I'll make sure to attend other class on axiomatic set theory, and by new textbooks that are recommended.