# A primer for set theory and operations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I'm taking [Stanford's Introduction to Logic through Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/logic-introduction/home/week/1) and the [supplementary reading material](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/coursera/note.php?chapter=preface) makes the following suggestion:

> The book presumes that the student understands sets and set operations, such as union, intersection, and so forth.

I have [a rudimentary understanding of set theory](https://xkcd.com/982/), however, I am wondering if there is a decent on-line primer or book available which I can review?

There are some good resources [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70666/set-theory-practice-problems) and I do have a copy of *Naive Set Theory* by Paul Halmos.

Comment: Great, ill make it this an answer instead of a comment, please tick if you are happy with this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Elements of Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384407) by Herbert Enderton

Comment: [Elements of Set Theory](http://azadimath.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Elements_of_set_theory_vol_1.pdf) by H. Enderton ch. 1 section 1 "Baby Set Theory" is just what I am looking for!